# Delegate a "task"(Ex:Runnable) inside a method of a Session Bean

Tags: java, multithreading, ejb-3.1, glassfish-4

I have a Stateless EJB method(**ejbMethod1**) that needs to call a web service operation(**wsOper1**), if this call fails It needs to call another web service operation(**wsOper2**).

My problem is: I don't need the returning of **wsOper2** to return from **ejbMethod1**! I want to delegate this work to another piece of my application and return immediately.

**Option1:**: My first approach to this problem was to use a global **LinkedBlockingQueue** for storing an Object representing the **wsOper2** I needed to do, and have N threads retrieving elements from this queue and executing the call.

**Option2:**: Create a Runnable and delegate to some global thread pool. There is one that I can use?

Or is another option that I'm not contemplating?

...
PS:
Im using Glassfish 4.1 & JRE8 and I'm new to the Java EE world :P

---

**UPDATED:**

I used a ManagedExecutorService to execute **wsOper2** asynchronously as a Runnable.

```
@Resource
private ManagedExecutorService executor;
```

Thanks Ryan :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the EJB spec:

> The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads. The enterprise bean must not attempt to start, stop, suspend, or resume a thread, or to change a thread’s priority or name. The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage thread groups.

See [Adam's Blog](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/conveniently_transactionally_and_legally_starting) for more information on EJBs and threading.

Comment: Great! If this correctly answers your question, can you accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer? Thanks.